# using 0 instead of '\0' in C program

Tags: c, while-loop, char, printf, c-strings

why my program did not go in infinite loop. I have not used `'\0'` for testing string end in while loop, instead of that I have use `0`. Does `'\0'` and `0` same in C?

If yes, then if `0` is in the middle of a string, then `printf` should end printing the string right there.
e.g.  `printf("%s", "hello how0 are you")`  should print  `'hello how'`

```
int main( )
{
    char s[ ] = "No two viruses work similarly" ;
    int i = 0 ;
    while ( s[i] != 0 )
    {
        printf ( "%c", s[i]) ;
        i++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: how below two differes?

Comment: printf("%s", "hello how0 are you")     vs    printf("%s", "hello how\0 are you")  why output differes in the above two cases?

Comment: Maybe this is not clear: a string like "ABC" is implicitely terminated by a null character, that's the reason your loop ends. So in memory "ABC" looks like this: `65 66 67 0`, 65 being the ASCII value of the `A` character etc.

Comment: @4386427 you're right, deleted the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'\0'` is the character with the *value* 0.  It is used to terminate strings in C.  So, yes, the loop

```
while ( s[i] != 0 )
```

works perfectly fine, although the more conventional way of writing it is

```
while ( s[i] != '\0' )
```

to emphasize that we're working with characters.

On the other hand, '0' is the character that *looks like* the number 0, although the *value* of this character in the ASCII character set is 48.  But in any case the value is not 0!  So when you write

```
printf("%s", "hello how0 are you");
```

it prints `hello how0 are you`, because the `0` is an ordinary character, and does not terminate the string.  If you wrote

```
printf("%s", "hello how\0 are you");
```

*then* you would have a null character, and it *would* terminate the string.

Answer (score 11):

`'\0'` has the same meaning as `0`, but `'0'` doesn't have the same meaning as `0`.

`printf("%s", "hello how0 are you")` will print `hello how0 are you`.

`printf("%s", "hello how\0 are you")` will print `hello how`.

Comment: And for fun OP could also try `printf("%s", "hello how\060 are you");`

Answer (score 10):

In the C language, '\0' means exactly the same thing as the integer constant 0 (same value zero, same type int).

Moreover, to someone reading the code, writing '\0' suggests that you're planning to use this particular zero as a character(null).

Answer (score 6):

`'\0'` and `0` are equal in C, because the ASCII (ANSI, UTF-8 etc.) character encoding defines the code of the `'\0'` character as `0`. In C, a character can be implicitly converted to an integer, and the resulting integer will be equal to the character code (for example, `'A'` will be converted to `65`).

If you set a character of a string to either `'\0'` or `0`, it will terminate the string.

Test code ([online](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/4oXmq6D)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Are they equal? Yes!
    char zc = '\0';
    char zi = 0;
    printf("%d\n", zc == zi); // Prints 1
    
    
    // Does setting a char to 0 terminate a string? Yes!
    char s[] = "hello, world";
    printf("%s\n", s); // Prints hello, world
    s[5] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", s); // Prints hello
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's also important that a string literal, like `s` in the code above, automatically has a terminating `'\0'` character, but it's NOT shown in the string literal.

Putting an internal `'\0'` character into a string literal might sound stupid, because the length of a string is defined as the number of characters until the first `'\0'`, and printf also prints only these characters. But internal `'\0'`s are really used in practice, e.g. when setting file type filters for the Open/Save File dialog on Windows ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#opening-a-file), [link](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/app_two.html)). Here the internal zero characters are used as filter delimiters:

```c
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
```

[image]

Comment: "'\0' and 0 have different types" They actually don't. Both have type `int`. By convention we use them in different situations, that's the only difference.

Comment: @Lundin I found this: "In C, character constants such as 'a' or '\n' have type int, rather than char." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal This can be verified using _Generic: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2j1vfVR Thanks, I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In C source code, `0` and `'\0'` are effectively the same: Each is an `int` constant with value zero. `'\0'` is used to indicate that we are working with characters, but it is the same as `0` to the compiler. (In C++, `'\0'` is a `char` instead of an `int`.)

The code for the display character “0” is not zero. In ASCII, it is 48. In any C implementation, it can be written as `'0'`. The value for this will always be positive and not zero, even if the C implementation uses some character encoding other than ASCII. So having a character “0” in the middle of a string will not act as a null terminator.

Answer (score 5):

I would of put this into comment but it would be too long for comment.

> Does '\0' and 0 same in C

I suggest you try this:

```
int main( )
{
    char s[ ] = "No two viruses work similarly" ;
    int i = 0 ;
    while ( s[i] != 0 )
    {
        printf ( "%d", s[i]); // this will print decimal values of
                              // all characters before `\0`
        ++i;
    }
    printf ("%d", s[i]); // this will print decimal value of `\0`
}
```

You can also do this:

```
printf("%d\n", '\0');
```

and it will answer your first question.

> If yes, then if 0 is in the middle of a string, then printf should end printing the string right there. e.g. printf("%s", "hello how0 are you") should print 'hello how'.

0 in "" or '' is treated as ASCII character thus try this:

```
printf("%d\n", '0');
```

that should give you decimal value of ASCII character '0'. and take a look at ASCII character table.

As fun exercise you can do this:

```
printf("%d\n", '0' - '\0');
```

Answer (score 5):

> Does '\0' and 0 same in C?

Yes, they are different ways of writing the same integer constant 0. The both constants in C (opposite to C++) have the type `int` and the same representations.

> why my program did not go in infinite loop. I have not used '\0' for
> testing string end in while loop, instead of that I have use 0

The condition in this while loop

```
while ( s[i] != 0 )
```

is equivalent to the condition

```
while ( s[i] != '\0' )
```

as it is pointed above.

> if 0 is in the middle of a string, then printf should end printing the
> string right there. e.g. printf("%s", "hello how0 are you") should
> print 'hello how'

This string literal

```
"hello how0 are you"
```

does not have an embedded zero character. This string with an embedded zero character can look for example the following way

```
"hello how\0 are you"
```

Answer (score 5):

`0` and `'\0'` are the same, but instead of just saying that, how about we explain what these different ways of typing zero actually are.

In C there are many situations where the integer value `0` can be used. Obviously, it can be used as a plain integer or array index. But it can also be used to create a null pointer. And yet another use is null termination of strings.

Since null pointers and null termination of strings are wildly different things, there's a big risk of mixing up the terms. At some point back in the dark ages, a distinction was made by referring to null pointers as `NULL` and creating a macro named like that, expanding to a null pointer constant. And the character 0 ("the null character") in the symbol table was referred to as `NUL` with a single L. Still confusing.

Furthermore, C never defined an escape sequence for null termination, as was done for line feed `\n`, tab `\n` and so on. So there existed no way to type the null termination character when part of a string.

Then someone (Kernighan & Ritchie?) came up with the idea to use other already existing escape sequences in C for this purpose. Inside string or character literals, we may use escape sequences to type out the index of a symbol in the table. This can be done using either octal or hexadecimal notation.

For example, the line feed character with decimal value `10` can be typed inside a string out as `\012` (octal) or `\xA` (hex). These are called octal/hexadecimal escape sequences. Example:

```
puts("test\ntest\012test\xAtest");
```

gives

```
test
test
test
test
```

Similarly, we can write the null character using escape sequences, either octal `\0` or hex `\x0`. The octal version became convention and de facto standard for null termination.

Answer (score 4):

0 is the ascii value of the character '\0'.
0 is NOT the ascii value of the '0' character.

Answer (score 4):

In C, for each character, there is a corresponding ASCII value for it, which is basically an integer number between 0 and 127.

For example, when you declare:

```
char a[] = "Hello";
```

Then, the array is actually having **6** elements, not **5**. You can test it using:

```
int n = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

The actual representation of that string has become: **Hello\0**

Here, you can see **\** sign, which is known as [Escape Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), which resembles an alternative interpretation of that character. Here **\0** represents ASCII value **0** on that index of char array. But, without the escape character, **0** is just a normal character - not an alternate representation.

Now if you want to view the corresponding ASCII value of each character of previous string - **Hello**, run this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("%d ", s[i]);
}

// Output: 72 101 108 108 111 0
```

Now about your original question:

> Does '\0' and 0 same in C?

ASCII **0** and char **0** are different. But char **\0** represents ASCII value of **0**.